# Двоеточие. Верно или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте,

> Джейн стало так страшно, что она начала шептать своему другу: нужно что-то делать, иначе...

Верно ли в вышеуказанном предложении стоит двоеточие? Очень похоже на прямую речь, однако здесь несколько странная пунктуация получается.

Comment: *Заранее спасибо Вам за Ваш ответ!* Всё прекрасно, но обращение именно к тому, кто это читает, расстраивает... :(

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Содержание высказывания с указанием его автора обычно оформляется в виде прямой речи, **но существуют и  другие варианты**: БСП со значением изъяснения; СПП с придаточным изъяснительным –  косвенная речь; представление слов автора в виде вводного предложения и др.

Поэтому выбор варианта оформления является авторским, обычно этот выбор определяется содержанием, структурой, стилем текта, а также необходимостью отделить прямую речь от авторских слов. Надо учитывать, что **наибольшую выделительную способность имеет прямая речь в обычном оформлении**, а наименьшую – СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.

Например, сравним два предложения: Мы с удивлением спрашивали: неужели Сильвио не будет драться? Я спросил: "Неужели Сильвио не будет драться?"

В приведенном примере автор, возможно, **не считал необходимым  выделять дословное высказывание и оформлять предложение в виде прямой речи.**

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант пунктуационного оформления допустим. Обычно используется для передачи мыслей и высказываний внутреннего или условного персонажа.

Строго говоря, в таком случае передаваемый текст не считается "прямой речью", пожалуй ближе всего так называемая *"косвенно-прямая"* речь (не путать с *несобственно-прямой речью*), весьма редкая конструкция в русском языке, но известная по иностранным языкам, например, английскому. Если Ваш текст - перевод с английского, то это точно она и есть. Но это  вопрос терминологии, не стоит уж очень сильно заострять внимание на том, как это назвать.

Вообще о типах прямой и непрямой речи и вариантах их оформления - тут.
http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_192